# HID compliant game controller Java interface

Tags: java, controller, usb, hid

I Have a USB RC flight simulator controller which is defined in the computer as "HID compliant game controller".  The problem is I don't know how to interface this controller to my Java application to receive inputs from it. I can't find even it's COMM port since it's not a serial one. Here is an image of the controller:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried JInput?

http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg2/ch11/index.html

Comment: i KNOW IT'S TOO LATE TO ANSWER!,but I am sorry. I tried it but It seems that it doesn't read all the axes of the controller. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I calibrated the controller and now it works like CHARM! THANKS A LOTTTTTTTTTTT! :D